# Session array only echoes last element

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have my session variable store array:

```
$outputs = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

    $_SESSION['row_id'] = $row['id'];
    $outputs = $row['sport_ime'].' '.$row['sezona'].'<a href=../view/modifikacije.php> Edit</a><br>';
    $_SESSION['output'] = $outputs;

}
```

And then on another page I call that variable:

```
$outputs = $_SESSION['output'];
echo ($outputs);
```

It just echoes one row. It is the last entry in my database.

Why doesn't it echo everything?

Comment: You are repeatedly overwriting the same variables...!

Comment: @deceze but what should I do?

Comment: Append to the array instead of overwriting it! `$array[] = $value;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$_SESSION['row_id'][] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['output'][] = $outputs;
```

Please read about [PHP arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), and generally consult the manual when you're stuck.

Comment: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: read the link I gave you with php arrays. Also read stack overflow help page to learn about what questions are appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You overwriting same `session id`. Use like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $outputs = $row['sport_ime'].' '.$row['sezona'].'<a href=../view/modifikacije.php> Edit</a><br>';
    $_SESSION[$row['id']] = $outputs;
}
```

Echo it:

```
$id = 5;
echo $_SESSION[$id]; // your output
```

**Note:** I advice that you should use `function` have `return array`

Comment: I want to echo all the entries in my database

Comment: create function and return all entries as array. Dont use session like  this types.